# SQL count values in different columns with date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to count values in different columns and with date ranges, but not when I have to do both things in the same time.

I have table with this example values:

```
   DATE    | Number1 | Number2 | Number3 | Number4 | Number5 | Number6  
2017-08-05 |   01    |   02    |   03    |   04    |    05   |   06
2017-08-04 |   02    |   03    |   04    |   05    |    06   |   07
2017-08-03 |   03    |   04    |   05    |   06    |    07   |   08
2017-08-02 |   04    |   05    |   06    |   07    |    08   |   09
2017-08-01 |   05    |   06    |   07    |   08    |    09   |   10
```

And now i want to have result like this for choosen data range (ex. from 2017-08-02 to 2017-08-03):

```
Number | occurrences
  03   |     1
  04   |     2
  05   |     2
  06   |     2
  07   |     2
  08   |     2
  09   |     1
```

How to do this in one SQL query?

Comment: This kind of problem is (nearly) always symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery and then normal `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT num, COUNT(*) AS Occurences
FROM (
  SELECT date_col, Number1 AS num
  FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date_col, Number2 
  FROM table_name
  ...
) AS sub
-- WHERE date_col BETWEEN ... AND  ... --specific range
GROUP BY num
ORDER BY num;
```

Anyway you should rethink your schema design.